# Is it possible to make a screen recording of an entire page in a browser window?

Tags: safari, video, screen-capture

I know how to take full-length screenshots of a given page, but what about video? Audio recording not necessary, but would be interested to know of any tactics or well-hidden browser extension recos for capturing a full page in all its animated glory.

Perhaps there's something about how the viewport handles graphics that makes recording off-screen animation unfeasible, so I encourage sharing efficient ways to stitch multiple videos or other reasonable (free? easy?) workarounds.

Answer (score 3):

Apple buit this functionality into Quicktime player and many people don't know it's there. In fact you can even record the screen of a connected iPad or iPhone.

Open Quicktime player and select New Screen recording... You will be given some brief instructions and then a button to click to start recording. When you are done, right-click on the Quicktime dock icon and end the recording.

Comment: Sorry maybe I should be more clear, I want to capture the entire scroll length of a web page as one continuous (moving) image. With this method I can only record the visible screen space (the viewport).

Comment: If you scroll while recording the movie that is what you will have. Also apps like SnagIt can capture the entirety of a web page as well.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking to have it all displayed at once without having to scroll, like the full-page screenshot feature that's built into most browsers, but as a video. I'm looking into SnagIt but am not seeing any specific mention of such a feature, I'd be very surprised if they offered it.